# Keep data correct after database-structure change

Tags: mysql

Right now I have the following table:

```
+----------------+
|  Sale table    |
+----------------+
| ID             |
| sale           |
| ...            |
| receiver_name  |
| receiver_email |
| ...            |
+----------------+
```

The important columns are `receiver_name` and `receiver_email`. The receiver is the person 'receiving' the object of a sale. Until now it was only possible to receive an object by mail. But in the next update it will also be possible to receive that object by other communication methods like for example SMS.

So for each sale the receiver of the sold object can select a communication method. For this question let's only consider e-mail and SMS. The new database-structure will have a extra table.

```
+----------------+
| Receiver table |
+----------------+
| ID             |
| receive_method |
| receiver_name  |
| receiver_email |
| receiver_telnr |
+----------------+
```

The updated sale table will have a foreign key to the new `Receiver table`:

```
+----------------+
|  Sale table    |
+----------------+
| ID             |
| sale           |
| ...            |
| receiver_id    |
| ...            |
+----------------+
```

This is necessary because my business logic can't know what method the user selected. Depending on the value of `receive_method` having the domain `("email", "SMS")` I'll collect the data from column `receiver_email` (if `receive_method == "email"`) or from column `receiver_telnr` (if `receive_method == "SMS"`).

I think this logic is pretty solid.

The problem, however, is that the Sale table is already filled with data! So I need a way to put the values of `receiver_name` and `receiver_email` from the old Sale table into the new version of the Sale table. And put the correct foreign key in place so the new Sale table still contains the information of the old sales before the update.

To complete this update, this are the steps I will take:

1. Create the new Receiver table
2. Put the values of `receiver_name` and `receiver_email` from the old Sale table into the new Receiver table.
3. Add the column `receiver_id` to the Sale table.
4. (Here I am stuck...)
5. Delete `receiver_name` and `receiver_email` from Sale table because it is referenced by the new column `receiver_id`.

I am stuck at step 4 though. How do I insert the foreign key in the new column `receiver_id` so the data stays correct?

Comment: Is `method` an `ENUM`?  Or a `SET`?  Your table names don't 'speak to me'.  Seems like you have "customers" and "sales"?  And the question is how to record that a particular customer has been sent notice of a sale?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your `Sale` table in three steps.

- First you have to add the `receiver_id` field as FK.
- Next you have to fill up `Receiver` table with data from `receiver_name` and `receiver_email`. Some denormalization emerge at this step because of data duplication.
- Finally you have to drop `receiver_name` and `receiver_email` from `Sale`.

Comment: But the question remains: In your second step, when I fill up `Receiver` with the data from `receiver_name` and `receiver_email`, how do I link the ID of the newly inserted rows to column `receiver_id`?

Comment: `Sale` and `Receiver` tables are in 1:1 relation - each row of  `Sale` should have a single corresponding row in `Receiver` and vv. So you can create an empty `Receiver` table with IDs from `Sale` and use it for JOIN.